# Is this sum equal to the Möbius function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fourier-series

In the wikipedia page [Uses of trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_trigonometry#Number_theory) under the section Number theory and in the page for the [Möbius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) there is an explanation for how to calculate the Möbius function from the GCD=1 pattern:

$\mu(n) = \sum\limits_{\stackrel{1\le k \le n }{ \gcd(k,\,n)=1}} e^{2\pi i \tfrac{k}{n}}$

Consider the infinite matrix starting:

$\displaystyle T(n,k) = \begin{bmatrix} +1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1 \\ +1&-1&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +1&+1&-2&+1&+1&-2&+1 \\ +1&-1&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +1&+1&+1&+1&-4&+1&+1 \\ +1&-1&-2&-1&+1&+2&+1 \\ +1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&-6 \end{bmatrix}$

defined by the recurrence:

$\displaystyle T(n,1)=1, T(1,k)=1, n>=k: -\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} T(n-i,k), n<k: -\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} T(k-i,n)$

Does the Möbius function $\displaystyle \mu(n)$ also equal the following:

$\displaystyle \mu(n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{k=n} T(n,k) \cdot e^{i 2 \pi \frac{k}{n}}$

As a Mathematica program this is:

```
Clear[nn, t, n, k, a, b];
nn = 15;
t[n_, 1] = 1;
t[1, k_] = 1;
t[n_, k_] := 
  t[n, k] = 
   If[n >= k, -Sum[t[n - i, k], {i, 1, k - 1}], -Sum[
      t[k - i, n], {i, 1, n - 1}]];
MatrixForm[Table[Table[t[n, k], {k, 1, nn}], {n, 1, nn}]];
MatrixForm[
 Table[N[Total[Table[1/n*t[n, k]*Exp[I*2*Pi*k/n], {k, 1, n}]]], {n, 1,
    nn}]]
```

And if needed, the matrix $\displaystyle T(n,k)$ as Excel cell formulas is:

European:

> =if(or(row()=1; column()=1); 1; if(row()>=column(); -sum(indirect(address(row()-column()+1; column(); 4)&":"&address(row()-1; column(); 4); 4)); -sum(indirect(address(column()-row()+1; row(); 4)&":"&address(column()-1; row(); 4); 4))))

American:

> =if(or(row()=1, column()=1), 1, if(row()>=column(), -sum(indirect(address(row()-column()+1, column(), 4)&":"&address(row()-1, column(), 4), 4)), -sum(indirect(address(column()-row()+1, row(), 4)&":"&address(column()-1, row(), 4), 4))))